# Что из себя представляют аргументы callback методов forEach() и sort()?

Tags: javascript

Почему в отмеченном участке кода переменные в функции-callback называются именно `a` и `b` и что они из себя представляют?

Что значит `m`, используемая в качестве первого аргумента callback метода `forEach()`?

```
var users = [{
    name: "Вася",
    surname: 'Иванов',
    age: 20,
    number: 3
}, {
    name: "Петя",
    surname: 'Чапаев',
    age: 25,
    number: 2
}, {
    name: "Маша",
    surname: 'Медведева',
    age: 18,
    number: 1
}];


function byField(field){
**Начало:**
    return function(a,b) {
        if( a[field] > b[field]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } **конец**

    }
}


users.sort(byField('age'));
users.forEach(function(m) {
    alert( m.name );**откуда м?**
});
```

Comment: И откуда м внизу, тоже не понятно. Для каждого элемента он берёт функцию, но зачем аргумент m, я не понимаю)

Код работает, сортирует. Но работа не совсем ясна его

Comment: Попробуй четко сформулировать мысли и описать их в теле вопроса. Поток сознания не привлекает внимание

Comment: у тя ощибка в фамилиях в объекте users, вася должен быть чапаев, а петя иванов))))))  шутка)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JavaScript вы можете передавать функции в качестве аргументов другим функциям.

Функция `byField()` в данном примере возвращает функцию, которая будет использована для сортировки методом `sort()`. Обратите внимание на выражение `return function(a, b) {...}` - оно прямым текстом говорит - вернуть функцию. Не результат ее выполнения, а именно ее саму.

То есть по сути данное выражение можно заменить на:

```
users.sort(function(a,b) {
    if( a[field] > b[field]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Почему использован именно такой подход, который описан вашим кодом? Потому что это весьма удачная модель дополнительного уровня абстракции, позволяющая писать более "говорящий" код, который легче читать, понимая при этом, о чем идет речь. Сравните пример, который я привел выше и тот, который в теле вопроса - однозначно `sort(byField("age"))` прочесть намного проще (и понять суть написанного).

Теперь о `a` и `b`.

Первым делом читаем о методе `sort` - [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), например. И видим, что метод сорт принимает в качестве параметра так называемый callback (она же та самая функция, о которой речь велась выше), который будет выполняться для каждого элемента массива `a` и следующего за ним элемента `b`. То есть внутри тела функции параметр `a` равен тому элементу, по которому сейчас проходит метод `sort`. А параметр `b` - следующему.

Наиболее наглядно можно показать на примере цикла:

```
for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var a = users[i];
    var b = users[i + 1];
}
```

Возможно, данное поведение будет проще объяснить на примере метода `forEach()`, потому как само по себе его поведение довольно просто.

Давайте попробуем реализовать этот метод, чтобы разобраться в том, как он работает.

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
    var i, length = this.length;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        callback(this[i], i);
    }
}
```

Что здесь происходит?
`this` указывает на сам массив (для конкретики - ваш `users`). Дальше цикл проходит по-порядку по каждому элементу массива, вызывая функцию callback, переданную в качестве первого аргумента функции, с двумя параметрами: первым, равным текущему элементу, и вторым - индексом текущего элемента.

Заметьте, никаких конкретных имен здесь не используется. А это значит, что вы можете использовать в своем коде абсолютно любые имена, которые захотите. Но их порядок будет играть значение.

Конкретно в вашем случае функция вызывается с одним параметром - `m`, который, поскольку является первым, будет равен текущему элементу в цикле. Если вы передадите еще и второй аргумент callback'у, то этот второй аргумент - как бы вы его не назвали - будет указывать на индекс элемента `m` в массиве.

Разумеется, реализация метода forEach выше чисто для ознакомления с принципом работы. Не реализовывайте ее так. Кроме того, у "настоящего" forEach есть еще некоторые параметры (в том числе и у callback'а), о которых всегда можно почитать в документации. Но вот используются они довольно редко.

После перепрочтения написанного выше, понял, что мысли можно организовать лаконичнее, что и попробую сделать сейчас.

Возьмем пример.

```
arr.forEach(function callback(item, index, array) {
   console.log(item, index, array);
});
```

Происходит следующее. Метод forEach пробегает циклом по каждому элементу массива, выполняя для каждого элемента функцию, переданную первым параметром (в данном случае я ее назвал `callback`). Каждый раз при вызове этой функции она вызывается с 3 параметрами (да, про третий я ничего выше не говорил). Но об этом вам волноваться совершенно ни к чему. Все это происходит за вас с целью сделать работу удобнее, проще и быстрее. Все, что вам следует знать - это то, что первый параметр коллбэка (как бы вы его не назвали, но в моем примере - `item`) указывает на текущий элемент, второй параметр - опять же, как бы его не назвали - на индекс этого элемента в массиве, а третий всегда указывает на сам массив, по которому мы проходим. Опять же, как бы не была названа эта переменная.

Имена вы всегда подбираете под себя, для конкретной задачи, чтобы было понятно, о чем идет речь.

Например:
users.forEach(function(user) {
    // Назвали переменную `user`, чтобы было видно, о чем речь.
});

elements.forEach(function(element) {
    // Сразу видно, что работаем с некими "элементами".
});

cats.forEach(function(cat) {
    // Перебираем котиков
});

С методом `sort` ситуация абсолютно аналогична, единственное различие состоит в том, что представляют из себя первый и второй параметр коллбэка (у вас они называются `a` и `b`, но имя, опять же, можно дать любое) немного другие вещи, а именно текущий и следующий элемент массива (как уже писалось выше).

Answer (score 0):

```
users.forEach(function(m) {
    alert( m.name );**откуда м?**
});
```

В данном коде переменная `m` является условной.
Можно сказать, что это "виртуальный параметр", который может называться так, как угодно создателю функции. Смыл его в том, что он обозначает наименование переменной, которая содержит каждый проход цикла.
То бишь, если простыми словами, то тут создаётся цикл, который проходит по содержимому `users`. Каждый его проход обращается к очередному содержимому объекта по-порядку. И каждый этот порядковый проход можно как-то озаглавить. Это улучшает читабельность кода и последующую работу с ним.
В данном конкретном случае, проходя по `users`, этот цикл перебирает пользователей, то бишь `users` содержит много виртуальных сущностей, которые можно озаглавить как `user`. Тогда становиться понятно, какие данные он обрабатывает внутри.
Для краткости/непонятности кода эту переменную почему-то обозвали не `user`, а `m`.

Аналогичная ситуация с переменными `a` и `b` - это условные обозначения для каких-то данных, которые потом будут сравниваться: `if( a[field] > b[field])...`